# How can I implement a variable-size table accesible by column name and row number in Java?

Tags: java, collections, datatable

The idea is to create a table to save and retreive information dynamically, so this is what I have done so far

- First, I thought about a `Map<String, List<Object>>` where each entry is a pair of `(column name, column values)`, and insertion of a value would be

```java
Map<String, List<Object>> table = new HashMap<>();
table.computeIfAbsent("Column Name", col -> new ArrayList()).add("value");
```

**Advantage**: each column is easily accessed by `table.get("Column Name").get(row)` and I can be sure about the columns name and count

**Disadvantage**: the row iteration is anti intuitive (having to access through column name and then row number) and I can't ensure the amount of values insterted to each column is the same.

- Now, if I exchange the Map and List roles, to use something like `List<Map<String, Object>>`, the Maps would act as the table rows, and insertion of a value would be

```java
List<Map<String, Object>> table = new ArrayList();
Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<>();
row.put("Column Name", "value");
table.add(row);
```

**Advantage**: the row iteration is more intuitive, each column is easily accessed by `table.get(row).get("Column Name")` and I can be sure about the rows count

**Disadvantage**: I can't ensure each inserted row will have the same columns.

Which one should I use? How can I improve them? Is there any better approach?

Comment: If I may ask, what is that you want to achieve by creating such tables? Do you want to query them? Or just use as a data structure?

Comment: @aksappy, with query them do you mean to filter columns or rows, or things like that? if yes, then no. By now I only want to insert some data on it and at the end of the execution save all that in a data base

Comment: You could just write it to the database in a transaction? And rollback if you don't like the result?

Comment: @DSantiagoBC If you need to have your Java data model interact with a SQL database, then read about ORM frameworks like Hibernate.  Hibernate lets you directly persist java entity classes, or collections of those classes, into a database table, with all the heavy lifting happening behind the scenes.

Comment: @RobOhRob I can't do it like that for several reasons, like how long the the DB would be blocked, or some mandatory fields obtained in different instants of the execution

Comment: Thanks, @TimBiegeleisen. I'll read about it.

Comment: If you have varying schema/columns then you can use a document store instead of a DB.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a slightly different option, which would use a plain 2D array of objects for the table, along with a separate hashmap for obtaining the column index based on a name.  For example, for a 3x3 table, we can try:

```
Map<String, Integer> cols = new HashMap<>();
cols.put("col1", 0);
cols.put("col2", 1);
cols.put("col3", 2);

Object[][] table = new Object[][];
table[1][2] = new String("Jon Skeet");
```

Then, to access the entry in the second row and third column we can try:

```
String value = table[1][cols.get("col3")];
```

Comment: The problem for me with this is I don't know how many columns or rows will be added to the table during execution. Maybe with a List of Lists instead of the array?